# Trying to append a new line item to a json file using python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to add a new line item to my json file for shipstation. I have the following python code which allows me to change the value of a key:

```
resp['items'][0]['sku'] = 'DISCOUNT3'
```

but i want to add a new `"items"` key

```
resp['items'][1]['sku'] = 'DISCOUNT3'
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet which you are using to add new items?

Comment: dictionary keys must be unique so you can't add new thing keyed with `items` in `resp`. You want `resp['items'].append({"sku": "DISCOUNT4"})`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding a new item to the list in Python is done with `append()` method:

```
new_object = {'sku': 'DISCOUNT3'}
resp['items'].append(new_object)
```

Comment: It would be nice to write a reason for downvoting next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention the type of `resp['items']`.

Actually, if your `resp['items']` is a **list object**, you cannot add a key to it, only an element. You can do it as follows

```
>>> resp['items'].append({'sku':'DISCOUNT3'}) # if resp['items'] is empty, it will be located at index 0
>>> resp['items'].append({'sku':'DISCOUNT3'}) # will be located at index 1
>>> resp['items']
[{'sku': 'DISCOUNT3'}, {'sku': 'DISCOUNT3'}]
```

But `resp['items']` is very unlikely to be a list, since you are about two add two identical elements. If `resp['items']` is a **dictionary object**, what you may want to do is

```
>>> resp['items'][0] = {'sku':'DISCOUNT3'}
>>> resp['items'][1] = {'sku':'DISCOUNT3'}
>>> resp['items']
{0: {'sku': 'DISCOUNT3'}, 1: {'sku': 'DISCOUNT3'}}
```

---

Or, since it is not easy to figure out what you really ask/want, know that keys in python dictionaries are [unique](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Which means that if you want to create a new key with `'DISCOUNT3'` as associated value, you will have, in one way or another, to add a new key. E.g.

```
resp['items'][0]['sku'] = 'DISCOUNT3'
resp['items'][0]['new_sku'] = 'DISCOUNT3'
```

And, be `resp['items']` a list or a dictionnary, it will be identical with this other pointer

```
resp['items'][1]['sku'] = 'DISCOUNT3'
resp['items'][1]['new_sku'] = 'DISCOUNT3'
```

Comment: this is a snippert from the json file i want to add to

Comment: "items": [
    {
      "adjustment": false,
      "createDate": "2017-05-12T06:48:38.997",
      "fulfillmentSku": null,
      "imageUrl": null,
      "lineItemKey": null,
      "modifyDate": "2017-05-12T06:48:38.997",
      "name": "DISCOUNT_TOTAL_ZOEY",
      "options": [],
      "orderItemId": 84406181,
      "productId": 10443850,
      "quantity": 1,
      "shippingAmount": null,
      "sku": "DISCOUNT3",
      "taxAmount": null,
      "unitPrice": -109.95,
      "weight": {
        "WeightUnits": 1,
        "units": "ounces",
        "value": 16.00
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

this worked thanks all

new_object = {'sku': 'miscellaneous','name': 'Miscellaneous','quantity': 1,'unitPrice': 5.00}
resp['items'].append(new_object)